# Count(*) automatically rounds

Tags: sql-server

I have a query where I am trying to determine what percentage of events happen on certain days and I'm getting nothing but zeroes back. I think (but am not sure) that something is causing my query to round. This is happening to me in SQL Server but not MySQL.

```
/* create the event table */
create table event (id int
                  , dayOf datetime
                  , description varchar(32)
);

/* add some events */
insert into event( id, dayOf, description ) values
( 1, '2018-01-01', 'Thing 1'),
( 2, '2018-01-01', 'Thing 2'),
( 3, '2018-01-02', 'Thing 3'),
( 4, '2018-01-02', 'Thing 4'),
( 5, '2018-01-03', 'Thing 5');

/* try to get % of events by day, but actually get zeroes */
select event_daily.dayOf, event_daily.cnt, event_total.cnt, 
       event_daily.cnt / event_total.cnt as pct_daily /* this is the zero */
from ( select dayOf, count(*) as cnt from event group by dayOf ) event_daily
   , ( select count(*) as cnt from event ) event_total;
```

Anticipated result:

```
DateOf    cnt  cnt  pct_daily
1/1/2018   2    5    0.40
1/2/2018   2    5    0.40
1/3/2018   1    5    0.20
```

Actual result:

```
DateOf    cnt  cnt  pct_daily
1/1/2018   2    5     0
1/2/2018   2    5     0
1/3/2018   1    5     0
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your problem is integer division. An integer divided by an integer will always return an integer. You need one part of the division to be a decimal, essentially. One easy way is just to add `1.0 * ` to the front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because SQL Server performs integer division, you can convert it into float first with `CAST`

```
select event_daily.dayOf, event_daily.cnt, event_total.cnt, 
       CAST(event_daily.cnt AS float) / CAST(event_total.cnt AS float) as pct_daily 
from ( select dayOf, count(*) as cnt from event group by dayOf ) event_daily
   , ( select count(*) as cnt from event ) event_total;
```

Comment: Nice! I pushed the cast() down into the subqueries, thinking it would be easier to put them in one place. Any performance issues jump out you with regard to that approach?

Comment: @MikePG it cost almost nothing in `SELECT` https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/643b6eda-fa03-4ad3-85a1-051f02097c7f/how-much-do-cast-statements-affect-performance?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 0):

Try the below approach

```
declare @TotalCount DECIMAL(18, 2)
select @TotalCount =  count(*) from #event

select
a.dayOf, a.DailyCount, a.TotalCount, CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (A.DailyCount/A.TotalCount)) AS pct_daily
FROM
(select 
    dayOf, Count(Id) AS  DailyCount, @TotalCount as TotalCount
from 
    #event
group by
    dayOf ) a
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ayyappa.k. I selected another answer because it gave additional context

Comment: May i know the what is the additional answer?

Comment: It's Colur Dalnet's answer above, the one with the check mark